# exec family with a file input

Tags: c++, linux, shell, input, exec

Hey guys I am trying to write a shell with C++ and I am having trouble with the function of using input file with the exec commands.  For example, the bc shell in Linux is able to do “bc < text.txt” which calculate the lines in the text in a batch like fashion.  I am trying to do likewise with my shell.  Something along the lines of:

```
char* input = “input.txt”;
execlp(input, bc, …..)    // I don’t really know how to call the execlp command and all the doc and search have been kind of cryptic for someone just starting out.
```

Is this even possible with the exec commands? Or will I have to read in line by line and run the exec commands in a for loop??

Comment: execlp is used to launch a single process. You will have to read your input file line-by-line and process each command individually.

Comment: execlp() is only really of use when you know the command and arguments at compile time, which is seldom if ever the case with a shell. You should assume you are going to be using the execv*() part of the exec*() family of functions.

Answer (score 3):

You can open the file and then `dup2()` the file descriptor to standard input, or you can close standard input and then open the file (which works because standard input is descriptor 0 and `open()` returns the lowest numbered available descriptor).

```
 const char *input = "input.txt";
 int fd = open(input, O_RDONLY);
 if (fd < 0)
     throw "could not open file";
 if (dup2(fd, 0) != 0)  // Testing that the file descriptor is 0
     throw "could not dup2";
 close(fd);             // You don't want two copies of the file descriptor
 execvp(command[0], &command[0]);
 fprintf(stderr, "failed to execvp %s\n", command[0]);
 exit(1);
```

You would probably want cleverer error handling than the `throw`, not least because this is the child process and it is the parent that needs to know.  But the `throw` sites mark points where errors are handled.

Note the `close()`.

Answer (score 1):

the redirect is being performed by the shell -- it's not an argument to `bc`.  You can invoke bash (the equivalent of `bash -c "bc < text.txt"`)

For example, you can use `execvp` with a file argument of `"bash"` and argument list

```
"bash"
"-c"
"bc < text.txt"
```

Comment: If he's writing a shell, he should not be using any other shell to handle this.

Comment: @BenVoigt that is true, but the statement "the bc shell in Linux is able to do “bc < text.txt”" suggested that OP wasnt aware that it was the shell that did the input redirection and not the `bc` command